# bootstrap icons missing internet explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap. Below is a screenshot of the code in internet explorer 7/8. The input-prepend icons are missing

```
  <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
      </span>
      <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text" placeholder="Email" class="span3 inputfield" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-prepend">
      <span class="add-on">
        <i class="icon-key"></i>
      </span>
      <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password"  placeholder="Password"  class="span3 inputfield" />
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="top10" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <span class="pull-left checkbox" for="user_remember_me">
          <label><input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Remember me</label>
        </span>
        <button class="btn btn-success pull-right right20" name="commit" type="submit" />
          Login
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

fixed it